# Invariant Violation: Expecting a parsed GraphQL document

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I'm getting the following error despite the mutation being wrapped in the `gql` tag:

```
Invariant Violation: Expecting a parsed GraphQL document. Perhaps you need to wrap the query string in a "gql" tag? http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/core.html#gql
```

This issue is only caused by the mutation code below, I have a query that works.

Code:

```js
<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  apollo: {
    createTask: {
      mutation: gql`
        mutation Task(
          $taskName: String!
          $taskDesc: String!
        ) {
          setSession(
            taskName: $taskName
            taskDesc: $taskDesc
          ) {
            id
            taskName
          }
        }
      `,
      variables() {
        return {
          taskName: this.res.data.task_name,
          taskDesc: this.res.data.task_description,
        }
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      createTask: '',
    }
  },
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Smart queries](https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/smart-query.html) are declared using the `apollo` object and are ran when the component mounts. If you have *queries* that you'd like to run this way, then your code would look something like this:

```
export default {
  apollo: {
    someQuery: gql`...`,
  }
}
```

However, when working with mutations, you generally don't want to run them on mount. Instead, you want to execute the mutation in response to some user action, like a button click. So the above syntax won't work for mutations. Instead, you need to call `this.$apollo.mutate` directly inside one of your methods:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    createTask() {
      this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: gql`...`,
        variables: {...},
        // other options
      }).then(result => {
        // do something with the result
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code results in the error: `Invariant Violation: Must contain a query definition.`

Comment: The mutation in my question is just an example, I do wanna run it when the user is redirected to a certain page, in my case the user would be sent to `website.com/token?code=CODE` and then I'd use the `code` to get a JWT token that I would store using apollo. I tried using this way but I can't seem to be able to call the method within `export default` using `createTask()`. Is there a way to call methods within `export default`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a lifecycle hook like [mounted](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and call `this.$apollo.mutate` from there. That said, since you're using SSR, you might consider doing this on the server-side before your page is even rendered.

Comment: I'm still new to web development and using nuxt, I'm gonna try to understand how to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently and it was because of an issue with an async import
I am using vue-apollo

```js
    async account () {
      return {
        query: (await import('src/modules/accounts/graphql/accounts.list.query.gql')),
......
```

I just had to replace that import with a require and it was happy again.

```js
    async account () {
      return {
        query: require('src/modules/accounts/graphql/accounts.list.query.gql'),
......
```